# Chebyshev polynomials factoring uniformly modulo all primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, orthogonal-polynomials

Consider the Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind $T_n(x)$ and its factorization in $\mathbb F_p$ for a given prime $p$. Most often, this factorization is not *uniform* (meaning that the irreducible factors have not all the same degree, as in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191049/which-criteria-for-uniformly-splitting-polynomials) thread). But the following seems to hold:

> For given $n$, $T_n(x)$ factors uniformly for all $p$ iff $n$ is a power of $2$.

More precisely: define $\nu(p):=\max( \nu_2(p-1),\nu_2(p+1))=\nu_2(p^2-1)-1$ (where as usual, $\nu_2(\cdot)$ is the multiplicity of the prime factor $2$).
Then it appears that each irreducible factor of $T_{2^k}(x)$ over $\mathbb F_p$ has degree $2^{max(k+2-\nu(p),0)}$.

How to prove this?

Comment: If you fix a prime $p \ne 2$, the roots of $T_{2^{k}}(x)$ in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}$ will have the form $\frac{\zeta^{r} + \zeta^{-r}}{2}$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $2^{k+2}$nd root of unity and $r$ is odd. You can prove your observation if you can determine how ${\rm Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}/\mathbb{F}_{p})$ acts on these roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $4n$th root of unity. Then $\alpha = (\zeta+\zeta^{-1})/2$ is a root of $T_n$. $\alpha$ generates the real subfield of
the $4n$th cyclotomic field, of degree $\varphi(4n)/2$ over $\mathbb Q$
(where $\varphi$ is the Euler phi function). Now $\varphi(4n) \le 2n$, with
equality if and only if $n$ is a power of 2. This implies that $T_n$ is irreducible
over $\mathbb Q$ if and only if $n$ is a power of 2. The uniformity follows
from that (since the field generated by a root is Galois, even cyclic).

Let $n = 2^k$. The degree of an irreducible factor mod $p$ is the smallest $e$ 
such that $p^e \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 2^{k+2}$. If $l = v(p)$, then this is 1 for $k \le l-2$ and $2^(k+2-l)$ for $k \ge l-2$ as claimed.